# Params Returning String Not Array

Tags: arrays, react-native, parameters, expo-router

Using `React Native` & `expo-router` I am passing some local params from a Home screen to a Details screen. I need to pass an array, however, it's passing a flat string as params.

### Code:

```
const language = "EN";

const offerDetails = (item) => {
  router.push({
    pathname: `/venue/${item.id}`,
    params: {
      name: item[language].name,
      description: item[language].description,
      tags: item[language].tags,
      review_average: item.review_average,
      review_count: item.review_count,
    },
  });
};
```

### Snapshot:

[image: illustration]

When printing `item[language].tags` within the offerDetails function the result is

```
LOG  Some Tag 1,Some Tag 2,Some Tag 3
```

Expecting

```
LOG ["Some Tag 1", "Some Tag 2", "Some Tag 3"]
```